# Could not remove Network Service with root authorization

Tags: objective-c, macos, networking, system-configuration

I am trying to delete a specific service name from my preferences, but unfortunately I get the 1003 error when trying to use the following functions: SCPreferencesLock, SCPreferencesCommitChanges, SCPreferencesApplyChanges.

The 1003 code it`s specific for kSCStatusAccessError, which means that I do not have root privileges, even if the AuthorizationRef is root.

```
    // Create AuthorizationRef
AuthorizationRef auth = NULL;
OSStatus status;

AuthorizationFlags rootFlags =  kAuthorizationFlagDefaults |
                                kAuthorizationFlagInteractionAllowed |
                                kAuthorizationFlagPreAuthorize |
                                kAuthorizationFlagExtendRights;

// Get default authorization
status = AuthorizationCreate(NULL, kAuthorizationEmptyEnvironment, rootFlags, &auth);

SCPreferencesRef preferences;

if (status == noErr) {
    preferences = SCPreferencesCreateWithAuthorization(NULL, CFSTR("personal.configuration"), NULL, auth);
    NSLog(@"Root autehntication");
} else {
    preferences = SCPreferencesCreate(NULL, CFSTR("personal.configuration"), NULL);
    NSLog(@"Default autehntication");
}


if(preferences == NULL) {
    NSLog(@"Could not create preferences");
}

CFArrayRef servicesArray = SCNetworkServiceCopyAll(preferences);
if (servicesArray == NULL) {
    NSLog(@"No network services");
}

// Get list of available services
SCNetworkServiceRef service;

for (int i = 0; i < CFArrayGetCount(servicesArray); i++) {
    // Get service reference
    service = (SCNetworkServiceRef)CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(servicesArray, i);
    // Get service anme
    CFStringRef serviceName = SCNetworkServiceGetName(service);
    NSString* strServiceName= (__bridge NSString *)(serviceName);

    NSLog(@"New network serivice found: %@", strServiceName);

    if ([strServiceName isEqualToString:@"Specific name"]) {

        if (!SCPreferencesLock(preferences, TRUE)){
            NSLog(@"\tFailed to call SCPreferencesLock: %d", SCError());
        }

        if(SCNetworkServiceRemove(service)) {
            NSLog(@"\tInternet Service successfully removed!");
        }

        if (!SCPreferencesCommitChanges(preferences)) {
            NSLog(@"\tFailed to commit preferences changes: %d", SCError());
        }

        if (!SCPreferencesApplyChanges(preferences)) {
            NSLog(@"\tFailed to apply preferences changes: %d", SCError());
        }

        SCPreferencesSynchronize(preferences);

        if (!SCPreferencesUnlock(preferences)) {
            NSLog(@"\tFailed to unlock preferences: %d", SCError());
        }
    }
}

CFRelease(servicesArray);
```

Comment: This code *should* do the right thing. Do you get an authorization dialog from the `SCPreferencesLock` call?

Comment: No authorization dialog is displayed.

Comment: Well, I solved the problem. It seems that this code is not working if it used in a Cocoa App.

I copied it in a Command Line Tool and run it and it worked. The authorization dialog also appeared. Well... this is strange but I am glad I found the problem.

Comment: It's an App Sandbox issue - you can't modify the System Configuration from a sandboxed app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments the issue is that the app is using the Cocoa sandbox.

> With App Sandbox, your app cannot modify the system’s network configuration (whether with the System Configuration framework, the CoreWLAN framework, or other similar APIs) because doing so requires administrator privileges.

If you want to modify the System Configuration framework, you cannot use the sandbox.

You can disable the sandbox by going to the apps entitlement file and changing the entry `App Sandbox` to `NO` and then the security dialog will appear.